# How to use same swiper in tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper Slider](http://idangero.us/swiper/) in tabs, but it doesn't work in tab "two".
What's going wrong?

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.tabs label {
  width: 50%;
  order: 1;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #838487;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: background ease .2s
}

.tabs .tab {
  order: 99;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #92B6D5
}

.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  display: none
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: #92B6D5
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked+label+.tab {
  display: block
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="tabs">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked">
  <label for="tabone">Tab One</label>
  <div class="tab">
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next" style="width: 575px;">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Next slide" aria-disabled="false"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Previous slide" aria-disabled="false"></div>
      <span class="swiper-notification" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span></div>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwo">
  <label for="tabtwo">Tab Two</label>
  <div class="tab">
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Next slide" aria-disabled="false"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-disabled" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Previous slide" aria-disabled="true"></div>
      <span class="swiper-notification" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[Link to website](https://mikij1029.github.io/web/020-navigation.html)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with **clearly** stating what your desired result is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 2):

The swiper's sizes can't be calculated correctly on hidden elements.
One solution is to update each swiper when you select its tab.

> **mySwiper.update();**
>   You should call it after you add/remove slides manually, or after you hide/show it, or do any custom DOM modifications with Swiper.
>   [Slider Methods & Properties](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#methods)

In the demonstration below, I'm selecting swiper containers by ID, based on the value of the changed radio button.

```js
new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  }
});

let tabInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.tabInput');

tabInputs.forEach(function(input) {

  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    let id = input.value;
    let thisSwiper = document.getElementById('swiper' + id);
    thisSwiper.swiper.update();
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.tabs label {
  width: 50%;
  order: 1;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #838487;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: background ease .2s
}

.tabs .tab {
  order: 99;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #92B6D5
}

.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  display: none
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background: #92B6D5
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]:checked+label+.tab {
  display: block
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="tabs">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked" class="tabInput" value="1">
  <label for="tabone">Tab One</label>
  <div class="tab">
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal" id="swiper1">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next" style="width: 575px;">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Next slide" aria-disabled="false"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Previous slide" aria-disabled="false"></div>
      <span class="swiper-notification" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span></div>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwo" class="tabInput" value="2">
  <label for="tabtwo">Tab Two</label>
  <div class="tab">
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal" id="swiper2">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add Arrows -->
      <div class="swiper-button-next" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Next slide" aria-disabled="false"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-disabled" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Previous slide" aria-disabled="true"></div>
      <span class="swiper-notification" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Also see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/framework7io/Framework7/issues/645) and [this comment](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/2276#issuecomment-339918354).